# ToolbarAndroid navIcon not displaying

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to display a ToolbarAndroid with a hamburger icon.  I'musing the code:

```
_buildToolbar (msg) {
    const navIcon = require("../../icons/menu.png");
    return (
        <ToolbarAndroid
            title={msg}
            style={{
                height: 56,
                alignSelf: "stretch",
            }}
            onIconClicked={this.props.openDrawer}
            navIcon={navIcon}
        />);
}
```

The toolbar displays, but the nav icon doesn't.  I get the warning `Failed prop type: Invalid prop navIcon supplied to ToolbarAndroid`. The file does exist, and looking under a debugger navIcon is defined.  Looking for any help here.  Using an Icon based toolbar is probably not a workable solution, as due to some of our customization features getting the right font would become difficult.

Edit:

Changing to:

```
        <ToolbarAndroid
            title={msg}
            style={{
                height: 56,
                alignSelf: "stretch",
            }}
            onIconClicked={this.props.openDrawer}
            navIcon={
                { uri: navIcon }}
        />);
```

Got rid of the warning but did not fix the display issue.

Edit2:

It looks like something with our build system here (which uses the same stack as our web build system, not the normal RN tools) is loading the files as a different data type-  its loading them as data uris.  I'm not sure what they normally are.  But when the ToolbarAndroid is passed a uri, it assumes it will be a file, an http/https url, or a name of a drawable in our drawable folder.  So it looks like we're going to need to debug our build system, or hard code this image (which being a hamburger icon isn't the end of the world).

Answer (score 0):

The navIcon format seems to be specific:

> Action Bar icons should be 32-bit PNGs with an alpha channel for transparency. The finished action bar icon dimensions, corresponding to a given generalized screen density, are shown in the table below.
>
> 18 x 18 px
>   24 x 24 px
>   36 x 36 px
>   48 x 48 px

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar

Also you can use `Icon.ToolbarAndroid` from react-native-vector-icons :
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: Icon.Toolbar won't work.  It works based on fonts.  Our app is a customizable platform, we can't be sure any font shipped with the app will actually be the right one for the given customer at runtime, and I don't think that library is customizable enough to allow runtime font overriding.

Comment: Agree, it will not. Did you try to play with the format ? The react-native custom implementation of the Toolbar not seems solve this restrictions

Comment: The image is downloaded from Google's list of material icons in 24px.  It should be appropriate.

Comment: Do you try your asset in a <Image /> ? It's working on my app with `navIcon={logo}` &  `import logo from '../Images/logo.png'` (png with alpha)

Answer (score 0):

This (ES6) code works on my app:

```
import navIcon from '../Images/navIcon.png'
...
<ToolbarAndroid
    title={'test'}
    style={{
      height: 56,
      alignSelf: 'stretch',
    }}
    onIconClicked={this.props.openDrawer}
    navIcon={navIcon}
/>
```

The `navIcon` file:

[image]